# Why is jquery concatenating string twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm trying to play an embedded Youtube video after a button click (`.playbutton`).

The video is embedded as an `iframe` within a `div` named `#youtubecontainer`.

The easiest way to achieve this is to append '`?autoplay=1`' to the `iframe`'s `src` attribute. (I know there is an API, but for now I need to do it this way.)

My HTML code is this

```
<div class="playbutton">
    <img class="playicon">
</div>

<div id="youtubecontainer">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/XeoFLxN5520" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Javascript code

```
$(function() {
    //This controls YouTube playback via button
    $('.playbutton').click(function() {
        $("#youtubecontainer iframe").attr('src', ($("#youtubecontainer iframe").attr('src') + '?autoplay=1'));
    });
});
```

However, this appends'?autoplay=1' to the src twice, so it reads as follows and fails:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/XeoFLxN5520?autoplay=1?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Maybe that's after clicking a second time?

Comment: @Scimonster I was calling my scripts file twice. This made me think about it!

Comment: Remember that most methods also accept functions. So something like this will be nicer and makes less DOM and method calls `.attr('src', function () {
            return this.src.replace('?autoplay=1', '') + '?autoplay=1';
        });`

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace that autoplay before you add it. Because when you second click on it, you are adding again the `?autoplay=1` what has still there before.

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ln6cv20p/)**

```
$("#youtubecontainer iframe").attr('src', $("#youtubecontainer iframe").attr('src').replace(/\?autoplay=1/, "") + '?autoplay=1');
```

Comment: I was calling my scripts file twice. This made me think about it!

Comment: With this, i've just added as an answer, now you can controll it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to save the original `src` of the `iframe` before the `click` event:

```
var source;
$(function() {
    //This controls YouTube playback via button
    source = $("#youtubecontainer iframe").attr('src');
    $('.playbutton').click(function() {
        $("#youtubecontainer iframe").attr('src', source + '?autoplay=1');
    });
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/notjtz3d/1/